# Match Url path with query string

Tags: java, regex, wiremock

I'm sending a request from SOAPUI to a wiremock server, and I'm attempting to match the url's.

This is the request that is being sent out: `/user/test/?and=query`

I've written the following regular expression:

```
stubFor(post(urlPathMatching("/user/test/\\?(and)\\=([a-z]*)"))
```

The problem is when I try to match the "?" when I use **one** backslash to capture the literal character, I get an error in Java saying:

```
"Illegal Escape Character"
```

**What I tried to do to resolve the problem:**
I know the solution is to use the second backslash to capture the "?" like this: "\?", but when I send the request I get an error saying the urls don't match because this is the request that is matched against the original one being sent from soap ui:

```
/user/test/\?(and)\=([a-z]*)
```

Can someone please help me on this?

EDIT: **Second attempt**
I've tried to use the dot notation to represent the "?" and "=" symbol. I've tested this on a regular expression tester and it checks out, but, It's still saying the url's dont match on soap ui.

Regular expression:  `stubFor(post(urlPathMatching("/user/test/.*(and).*([a-z]*)")).atPriority(1)`

mismatched url: `/user/test/.*(and).*([a-z]*)`

Comment: Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: To match `/user/test/?and=query` you need to escape slash and question mark. So try: [`\/user\/test\/\?and=query`](https://regex101.com/r/Rw1Mn4/1/). Or more generally `\/user\/test\/\?\w+=\w+`

Answer (score 3):

When you are using `urlPathMatching()` you shouldn't put your query parameters in the url. That approach only works for `urlEqualTo()`.

Instead you should specify the parameters separately using `withQueryParam()`, so your stub setup should be:

```
stubFor(post(urlPathMatching("/user/test/")).withQueryParam("and", matching("[a-z]*")));
```

Answer (score -2):

`\\` is just escapse the \, you should add one more \ before ? to escapse ?.
Just like this:
`stubFor(post(urlPathMatching("/user/test/\\\?(and)\\=([a-z]*)"))`

Comment: Hi @Thang X. Vu, I've tried that but it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: Ah ha, i see, you forgot to escapse two / before the words user and test. Put the \ and try it again.

Comment: hmm I didn't quite understand, do you mean something like this: ///user/test?

Comment: No, it exactly is: `\/user\/test\/\\\?(and)\\=([a-z]*)`.

Comment: but this doesn't work in Java. I get an error message saying illegal Character escape when i try \/user

Comment: I'm sorry, i haven't test it, it should be: `\\/user\\/test\\/\\?(and)\\=([a-z]*)` in Java.

Comment: Im using wiremock, so the way i write the regular expression for patching url path is a little different as sown in my post

Comment: I haven't use it, but i saw a problem in your regular expression is missing escapse for the first 3 / chars. You could try to escapse them and try again.